# Javascript function works when called and clicked but does not reflect any changes made in the function itself

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I haven't done programming in months so I really cannot pinpoint what's going on. This function(and the rest of the functions as well) works perfectly before I left this project and now that I revisited it, I'm having this issue. I'm using NetBeans 8.0 and every files in my project folder is organized well (each files are separated into subfolders)

My main problem is this: This javascript function works fine when called, and does not when I comment it out. If I ctrl+click on the function name, it redirects me to the .js file the function is located.

```
//alerts in PSMA doesn't show up but graph is affected if I comment out this method:
PSMA("2014", "2014", "01", "04", category, "Monthly", area);
```

However, if I do some modifications inside the function, let's say I add an alert("Hello"); at the very least, it doesn't show any pop ups when save then re-run or refresh my page. Even when I comment out the whole function, the function called still works and I have no single clue why or how.

```
function PSMA(rangeY1, rangeY2, rangeM1, rangeM2, category, timePeriod, area) {
alert("Hello");
psDegree = 2;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../AreaManager/Sales/DAOs/PSMAQuery.php',
    data: {rangeY1: rangeY1,
        rangeY2: rangeY2,
        rangeM1: rangeM1,
        rangeM2: rangeM2,
        areaID: area},
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert("yolo");
        var arr = [], oArr = [];
        arr = JSON.parse(data);......
```

I am 100% sure I have done the right script imports, file placements, and everything, it's just that I can't proceed without solving this 'mysterious' part. As I have said before, all my functions works fine when I left this project. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: caching, did you try CTRL-F5 ?

Comment: do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: CTRL-F5 worked! Thank you sir @adeneo. My question is now solved! :)